# How to add an imageview at a fix point x-y of another imageview (not the container) in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I have a relative layout in which an imageview is placed. In onTouch event of this imageview I have made a code to add another imageview (a marker image) dynamically on that image at the x y point of the container.

I want to zoom my main imageview and also want to reside the dynamically added imageview at the fix location of the image (not the container).

That is, when I zoom my main image then the marker image should also move where the main image zoomed and will be fixed at point x,y of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Since your container is a relative layout, you can make your inner imageView to align  to the outer imageView, and put top margin and left margin. x and y are the coords of the point you want to put the image in, some_x and some_y is the size of innerView

```
ImageView outerView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.outer_image_view);
ImageView innerView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inner_image_view);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(some_x, some_y)
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.outer_image_view);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.outer_image_view);
rlp.leftMargin = x;
rlp.topMargin = y;
innerView.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```